# How to process Flask requests synchronously

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to create a Flask API that will receive multiple HTTP GET requests and processes them one by one in the order they were received.

The subprogram the GET request calls is a pywinauto program, so it is important that only one instance of it gets called at a time.

I have tried using Celery + RabbitMQ and a plain python Queue.

I was thinking some sort of queue would be the way to go, but everything I have tried so far has resulted in the requests being processed concurrently.

Any guidance would be helpful.

My route with Celery task

```
@app.route('/ClientEntry', methods=['GET'])
def createClient():
    crmid = request.args.get('crmid')
    if crmid:
        result = inputClient.apply(args=[crmid])
        print('inside '+ result.get(timeout=120))
        return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'} 
    else: 
        raise BadRequest('CRM ID cannot be empty')
```

My Celery tasks.py (running in a Windows environment so the `FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING` variable had to be set manually)

```
from celery import Celery
import os
os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '0') #tried both 0 and 1
os.environ.setdefault('CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER', 'True') #tried both with and without this, 'True', 'False', '0', and '1'
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://guest@localhost')

@app.task
def inputClient(crmid):
    uiInputClient(crmid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch your celery worker set `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY` to `1` and only launch a single worker. This will make it so only one task runs at a time.

For more information check the [celery docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.0-archived/configuration.html#concurrency-settings).

Comment: Does this have to be set in a config file, or is there a way to set it manually?

Comment: I was able to set the `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY` to 1 but it is still running more than one task at a time

Comment: How are you starting celery? What's the full command and the output?

Comment: I guess I miss understood the documentation on how you are supposed to implement celery with another program. I didn't have a make_celery function, so when I was starting celery in a different terminal, it wasn't using that instance of it. Once I set that up correctly, it all started working, including the concurrency. First time is always the hardest. Thank you for your help